# display module only on the front page of virtuemart joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

hi i want to display module only on the front page of virtuemart and dont want that module on inner pages. i have search about this, but did not get anything.

I tried to used this code but it does not effect.

```
  <?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='productdetails') { ?>
  <div id="productmod"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="productdetails" /></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Can anyone help me to figureout this problem

Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 0):

take a look on the answer, and `var_dump` the `$menuList` to get all the menus, then just get the specific menu and apply your condition..

```
// Get default menu - JMenu object, look at JMenu api docs
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();

// Get menu items - array with menu items
$menuList = $menu->getMenu();

// Look through the menu structure, once you understand it
// do a loop and find the link that you need.
var_dump($menuList);
```

take a look on the give link [how to determine the front or default page](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page)